# Iterate through a collection using an object in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, iteration

I'm failing to iterate through an array and need some assistance with creating an iterator that works.
I have a preference object which has the user service preferences and an array of the service object, I need to iterate through the service array using the preference to filter out the services.

Preference object:

```
{
    "service_1": "option 1",
    "service_2": "option 2",
    "service_3": "option 3"
}
```

Service Array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "service_name": "option 1",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "service_name": "option 2",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "service_name": "option 3",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "service_name": "option 4",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "service_name": "option 5",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "service_name": "option 1",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "service_name": "option 2",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "service_name": "option 3",
    "desc": "Adfds",
    "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
  }
]
```

My source code:

```
$preferance = preferances::all();
        
if($preferance->isNotEmpty()){
  foreach($preferance as $item){
    $services = services::select('id', 'service_name', 'desc', 'image')->where('service_name', $item)->get();;
 }
 return $services;
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the field on `preferances` that you want to compare to `services`? ... how does `preferances::all()` give you the array in the post above?

Comment: By reading your code, I guess you're trying to retrieve the items by the preference, try a `groupBy('service_name')` instead of a where with the item.

Comment: @lagbox name of the fields is service_1, service_2, service_3. response coming from preferances::all() is a object

Comment: so `preferances` table has the fields `service_1`, `service_2`, `service_3` ?

Comment: @lagbox yes it has those fields

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro it return a SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;

Comment: In the foreach loop `$item` is an object, so in the where condition you must compare against a property on the `$item`, not the entire object. For instance `where('service_name', $item->service_1)`

Comment: @Donkarnash that responses  success fully but only returns that specific service. I need it to return a set of services based on the preference object

Comment: What does preferences::all() return? Should return an array of preference objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the information above, use `$services[]` to store objects in array.

```
$preferance = preferances::all();
        
if($preferance->isNotEmpty()){
  foreach($preferance as $service => $option){
    $service = services::select('id', 'service_name', 'desc', 'image')->where('service_name', $option)->get()[0];
    if ($service) {
        $services[] = $service;
    }
 }
 return $services;
}
```

Comment: response with " ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Sleek_Beta\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php on line 1307 " and when i remove the [0] at the end of $services[] responses with an empty array like that -> " [] "

Comment: Thats because it returns a collection. You can get the first item of the collection by using `->first()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: @O.Moloi what is the output of `services::select('id', 'service_name', 'desc', 'image')->where('service_name', $option)->get()` ?

Comment: @HamidAli it is responding accordingly now

Comment: ````[
    [],
    [],
    [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "service_name": "Mobile Spa",
            "desc": "Adfds",
            "image": "1593267252.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "service_name": "Hair",
            "desc": "Asfsdfdgh",
            "image": "1593273135.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "service_name": "Nails",
            "desc": "Gdsfsdg",
            "image": "1593273183.jpeg"
        }
    ],
    []
]````

Comment: nice, @O.Moloi hope this answers your question, I've updated the answer, feel free to up-vote it.

Comment: @HamidAli Just a question why use `get()[0]` when there's already `first()` available for collections

Comment: @Donkarnash thanks for pointing out, `first()` is much preferable than `get()[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$preferance = preferances::all();
        
if($preferance->isNotEmpty()){
  foreach($preferance as $key => $value){
    $services[] = services::select('id', 'service_name', 'desc', 'image')->where('service_name', $value)->first();
 }
 return $services;
}
```

This should get you the desired output is preference:all() returns an object

However if preference::all() returns an array of `preference` objects then you can nest the foreach

```php
$preference  = preference::all();

if($preference->isNotEmpty()){
    foreach($preference as $item) {
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {
            $services[] = service::where('servie_name', $value)->first();
        }
    }
}

return $services;
```

Or if you are interested in only the first preference object you can use preference::first().

If `$preference` is an object (Eloquent Model Object) having structure like

```
{
    "service_1": "option_1",
    "service_2": "option_2",
    "service_3": "option_3"
}
```

and $preference is an object then you can improve readability using `whereIn`

```php
$options = [];
foreach($preference as $key => $value) {
    $options[] = $value;
}

$services = services::whereIn('service_name', $options)->get();
```